# JSON FIle not updating - getting "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" error

Tags: c#, json

Using C#, I am trying to change values in a JSON file however the values are not changing. 
Below is the JSON - I intend on changing.

```
{
    "client": {
        "name": "ClientName",
        "pageTitle": "PageTitle",
        "serverId": 234
     },
    "connection": {
        "router": {
            "webSocketURL": "wss://pbnasdadasdasd",
            "signalRUrl": "https://pbncrasdasdasdasd",
            "endPoint": "https://pbncasdasdadasd",
            "type": "BabelFish",
            "protocol": "WebClientGameplayProtocol.WebClientGameplayProtocolDefinition",
            "transport": [
                "webSockets"
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

This is what my C# code looks like in the method.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(Jsonfile);
            dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            jsonObj["client"]["serverId"] = "7001";

            jsonObj["client"]["connection"]["router"]["webSocketURL"] = "wss://xrouter.program.eu";
            jsonObj["client"]["connection"]["router"]["signalRUrl"] = "https://xrouter.program.eu/h";
            jsonObj["client"]["connection"]["router"]["endPoint"] = "https://xrouter.program.eu/";
```

When I run my code I get a 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" error, and not sure why when there are already values in that area. ****I no longer get this error - My path was incorrect in the jsonObj****

see error below:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Below is the XML" -> not the JSON? It seems that done of those properties in your JSON file (it really would be helpful for our testing if you actually provded JSON rather than screenshots). Also, in your screenshot you have edited that line of code while the application was running, and rebuild is required for your changes to be reflected.

Comment: @John Sorry for the confusing, I have edited the post. 
I edited the URL during runtime for security purposes to take a screenshot.

Comment: Can you post it as one complete file, please? At the moment it looks like you have two different files, and it's unclear where everything exists within the full JSON file. Please include everything including the root object.

Comment: SUre - So I see where I went wrong on the error - this has now been fixed, my rooting was incorrect. 

However, I am still not getting the changed values. 

Sure @John

Comment: @John Updated the Json

Comment: In your code you're trying to update ["client"]["connection"], but that doesn't exist in your file. You have "client" and "connection", but not "connection" as a child of "client"

Comment: Yes I pick that up the second I posted the full Json segment. 
However the overall update still doesnt work.

Comment: Assuming you've fixed your code to to deal with that, I can't find issues on the JSON side of things. See [here](https://rextester.com/WZFJTM74658).

Comment: That I have, Thank you @John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to `jsonObj["client"]["connection"]..` where `["client"]` doesnt exist for `connection` properties. also try using `JObject.Parse`

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(Jsonfile);
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
jsonObj["client"]["serverId"] = "7001";

jsonObj["connection"]["router"]["webSocketURL"] = "wss://xrouter.program.eu";
jsonObj["connection"]["router"]["signalRUrl"] = "https://xrouter.program.eu/h";
jsonObj["connection"]["router"]["endPoint"] = "https://xrouter.program.eu/";

Console.WriteLine(jsonObj.ToString());
```

Output

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "ClientName",
    "pageTitle": "PageTitle",
    "serverId": "7001"
  },
  "connection": {
    "router": {
      "webSocketURL": "wss://xrouter.program.eu",
      "signalRUrl": "https://xrouter.program.eu/h",
      "endPoint": "https://xrouter.program.eu/",
      "type": "BabelFish",
      "protocol": "WebClientGameplayProtocol.WebClientGameplayProtocolDefinition",
      "transport": [
        "webSockets"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json hierarchy, for you to update websocket url, you need to use the below line of code to update the attribute value

```
jsonObj["connection"]["router"]["webSocketURL"] = "wss://xrouter.program.eu";
```